# Alert for friend’s activity on facebook

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-apps

Is it possible to receive alert for a particular friend’s activity on Facebook? For instance when he posts/updates on his wall, likes, uploads pics etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is something called "stalking" someone, and Facebook has a feature for that (though not actually created for stalking people).

In Facebook, there is something called the "Close Friends" list on Facebook. If you want to know everything that your friend did, you would add him/her onto this list and even his/her likes will appear on your feed.

Note: Some people don't like the feeling of being "stalked", so use this sparingly.

[Source](http://jeannieinabottle.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Stalk-People-on-Facebook-Using-the-Close-Friends-Feature)

Comment: this doesn't send alert or notification

Comment: Yes it does, it sends one for every event

Comment: You can set whether you get notifications for this list by clicking on Close Friends on the left and then Notifications at the top.

Comment: I am not getting any notification,I have to open close friend and see the activity

Comment: @livinggourmand: Did you set Notifications On at the top of the Close Friends page?  Also check Account Settings » Notifications » Close Friends Activity.  https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications

Comment: @mark4o Yes both he the settings are done. I have checked for all updates ie. photos,comments & likes,music etc also under Settings » Notifications » Close Friends has been activated "On Facebook". But I m only getting notification for profile picture update , not for comment & and likes.

Comment: @livinggourmand: On the Close Friends page click on Manage List and ensure all types of updates are checked.  If you are missing updates for particular people, hover over their name or profile picture, then Friends, ensure Show in News Feed is checked, choose Settings... from popup menu, and ensure that All Updates and all of the types of updates are checked.